# Python Pandas to csv without double quotes

Tags: pandas

My code below converts spark dataframe to Pandas to write it as a CSV file in my local.

```
myschema.toPandas().to_csv("final_op.txt",header=False,sep='|',index=False,mode='a',doublequote=False,excapechar='"',quoting=None)
```

Output of above command:

```
"COLUMN DEFINITION|id"|int
"COLUMN DEFINITION|name"|string
```

Note that in my 'myschema' dataframe there are no double quotes. While writing to CSV double quotes are coming. Desired output is without double quotes as below:

```
COLUMN DEFINITION|id|int
COLUMN DEFINITION|name|string
```

I thought setting `doublequote=False,excapechar='"',quoting=None` these will solve it. But no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Pass **`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`** to `to_csv` command:

```
myschema.toPandas().to_csv("final_op.txt",header=False,sep='|',index=False,mode='a',doublequote=False,excapechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Comment: I am getting '_CSV.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set' issue. Any additional setting I need to pass ?

Comment: You need to remove `quoting=None` and replace with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

Comment: yes. I did replacement only. I just added 'escapechar="\\" also. But my output is coming as : COLUMN DEFINITION|\id\|int. Means '\' is getting prefixed with '|'. so I tried to set escapechar="\" and escapechar="". But both are giving error.

Comment: Yes, I tried. That's when output is coming as : COLUMN DEFINITION|\id\|int. Means double quote is getting removed but '\' is getting prefixed with '|'.

Comment: Did you try escaping with `double slash` like ("\\"). Also try this: `quotechar="",  escapechar="\\"`.

Comment: Yes. I tried quotechar="", escapechar="\\". that's when double quote is getting removed but '\' is getting prefixed with '|'.

Comment: When I use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` instead of `quoting=None`, I get a syntax error = "NameError: name 'csv' is not defined". If I use `quoting=None` I get no such error, but still get the double quotes surrounding my output in the CSV.

Comment: @Korzak If you `import csv` you will get the constant imported along with the other features. If you do something like `from csv import writer` you will need to amend that to e.g. `from csv import writer, QUOTE_NONE` and then specify `quoting=QUOTE_NONE` without the `csv.` module specifier.